# Populating a checkbox list with an array

Tags: javascript, user-interface, after-effects

I'm trying to build a simple interface with a list populated by an array. My proplem is I don't know how to make the a variable number of "projectList"

I've tried the following

```
var win = new Window('palette', 'Character Importer', undefined, {resizeable:true});
var w = buildUI();
w.show();


//build UI
function buildUI(){

     if (win != null) {

        for(i=0; i<lines.length; i++) {


        win.projectList = win.add ("checkbox", undefined, charNames[i]);
        win.projectList.alignment = ['left','center'];

        }
```

But win.projectList only contains the value for the last name, I understand it's becuase I keep duplicating it. How can I create new properties? I've tried adding a [i] after projectList with no luck.

Thanks in advance

Comment: are you trying to create new checkbox or just trying to populate it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
win.projectList = [];
for (...) {
  var cb = win.add(...);
  win.projectList.push(cb);
}
```

Comment: Thanks!! That works, but I've lost my win.projectList.alignment = ['left','center']; How do I re implement that?

Comment: never mind... cb.alignment = ['left','center'];

Thanks again